# Is there a way to draw a rect using after a function call using the Pygame library? after a button press

Tags: python, pygame

I am building a little game that is similar to an old arcade game where you stack blocks. What I am trying to do is after every space key press the program would draw a block wherever in the screen i happen to hit the space key while the block is moving from left to right or vice versa. I managed to get the current coordinates wherever the block is after i hit the space key and use those to draw a new one, while the new block is moved up in the screen.

This is the print out to the console i am using to see what gets passed.

```
second space key pressed
next_block() 228 660
second space key pressed
next_block() 11 600
second space key pressed
next_block() 18 540
```

```
def game_loop():
    sq_x = 60
    sq_y = 660
    sq_change_x = 7
    bumped = True
    while bumped:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    print("second space key pressed")
                    # pass the current coords to next_block()
                    next_block(sq_x, sq_y)
                    # moves the block -60 after every space bar key press
                    sq_y -= 60

        gamedisplay.fill(black)
        # draws the initial block that is positioned at the bottom of the window
        pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, blue_block, [sq_x, sq_y, 240, 60])
        # boundaries so the block only is animated within the window
        sq_x += sq_change_x
        if sq_x > 360 or sq_x < 0:
            sq_change_x = sq_change_x * -1

        game_background()

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)
```

This is the function that is supposed to draw the rectangle after the key press, but it doesn't do anything to the screen....it doesn't draw anything.

```
def next_block(sq_x, sq_y):
    # gets called after the space key is press and draws a block at the given coords.
    pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, yellow_block, [sq_x, sq_y, 240, 60])

    print("next_block()", sq_x, sq_y)
```

can someone help me understand why this logic is not working? the function gets the coordinates but does not draw anything. This is just a little side project i am doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is not working, because the screen is cleared in every frame (`gamedisplay.fill(black)`).
Since the blue block is moving dynamically, you've to redraw the entire scene (all the blocks) in every frame.

Create an array of the block coordinates (`blocks = []`). When <kbd>SPACE</kbd> is pressed, then add the current coordinates to array (`blocks.append((sq_x, sq_y))`). Draw the blocks at the coordinates sorted in the array in a `for`-loop, in the main application loop:

```py
blocks = []
while bumped:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                print("second space key pressed")

                # store coordinate in blocks
                blocks.append((sq_x, sq_y))

                # moves the block -60 after every space bar key press
                sq_y -= 60

    gamedisplay.fill(black)

    # draw the blocks in the list
    for pos in blocks:
        pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, yellow_block, [*pos, 240, 60])

    # draws the initial block that is positioned at the bottom of the window
    pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, blue_block, [sq_x, sq_y, 240, 60])
```